# How to programatically check this iphone style checkbox?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

I am using [this](http://awardwinningfjords.com/2009/06/16/iphone-style-checkboxes.html) iphone style checkbox. All checkboxes are checked by default. If it is unchecked, a modal is shown, which has a form and all. When I close this modal, I want the checkbox to be enabled again.

This is the JS that shows the modal when the checkbox is changed to false:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var onchange_checkbox = $('.on_off :checkbox').iphoneStyle({
    checkedLabel: 'Confirm',
    uncheckedLabel: 'Edit',
    onChange: function(elem, value) {
        if($(elem)[0].checked==false){
            $('.modal').show();
            $("body").append('<div class="modalOverlay">');
        }
    }
  });
});
```

This is the table of checkboxes:

```
%{for(int i=0;i<confirmAtt.size ();i=i+9){}%
<tr>
<td>${confirmAtt.get(i)}</td>
<td>${confirmAtt.get(i+1)}</td>
<td>${confirmAtt.get(i+2)}</td>
<td>${confirmAtt.get(i+3)}</td>
<td>${confirmAtt.get(i+4)}</td>
<td>${confirmAtt.get(i+5)}</td>
<td>${confirmAtt.get(i+6)}</td>
<td>${confirmAtt.get(i+7)}</td>
<td>${confirmAtt.get(i+8)}</td>
<td class="modalInput on_off"><input type="checkbox" id="on_off_${i}"
    checked="checked" /></td>
</tr>
%{}}%
```

The modal with the close button:

```
    <div class="modal" id="aModal">
        <p>
            <button class="close" onclick="foo();">Close</button>
        </p>
    </div>
```

which calls this function:

```
function foo(){
    $('.modal').hide();
    $('.modalOverlay').remove();
    onchange_checkbox.prop('checked', !onchange_checkbox.is(':checked')).iphoneStyle("refresh");
    //tried changing this line to
    //$('.on_off').attr("checked" , true);
    //doesn't work
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by enabled again? You want to it be set to checked?

Comment: Yes, thats what I meant. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to set the checkbox back to checked, you can use the following code:

```
$(window).load(function() {

      var onchange_checkbox = ($('.on_off :checkbox')).iphoneStyle();


      onchange_checkbox.prop('checked', !onchange_checkbox.is(':checked'))
      .iphoneStyle("refresh");


});
```

http://jsbin.com/urocug/1/

**Update**

Sorry, I now see you tried to implement this within your code. The problem is that you are declaring the checkbox as a variable within `$(window).load(function() {` while you try to access the same variable outside the scope of `$(window).load(function() {`

---

Ideally what you need to do is move your `foo(){}` function into your `$(window).load(function() {`:

Comment: Oh yes, that did it. I declared the variable outside the `$(window).load()` and now it works. I hope declaring it outside is not a bad practice.

Comment: Unless there was some particular reason for using $(window).load() in the first place, I would just replace it with `$(document).ready(function() {` and make sure all your jquery is contained within it. That way you won't have any problem with accessing your global variables.

Comment: I used `$(window).load` because it was shown so in the examples. I will try replacing it as you suggested. Thank you!

Comment: I noticed it in the examples, I tested $(document).ready() in my test jsbin and it worked fine. You should really be putting all your jquery code within $(document).ready() as a best practice.

Comment: It didn't work on the app. I changed the same in your jsbin, and it worked. I don't understand why it is happening.

Comment: What technology are you using? If your using jquery-mobile or phonegap or something like that then $(document).ready() may not work.

Comment: Odd, should work fine with play-framework, do you get any errors in the console? Throw the entirety of your code in a jsbin and I will take a peek. Otherwise I would revert to using window.load if that was working for you.

Comment: Please give me some time, I am on a pretty tight deadline here. I promise I will reply here with a jsbin.